# How to create Math Table with this?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to create a simple math table (times). But i'm bit confuse how to do it. For now i can create something like this.

```
echo "<table>";

for ($i = 1; $i <= 11; $i++ ) { 
$k=1;
   echo "<tr>";
   if($i==1)
    echo "<td>x</td>";
   else{
   $k=$i-1;
   echo "<td>$k</td>";
   }

    echo "<td>".$k ."</td>";

    for ( $j = 2; $j <= 10; $j++ ) {

            echo "<td>".$k * $j."</td>";

        }

    echo "</tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
```

Here is what i get from above

```
x   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
2   2   4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18  20
3   3   6   9   12  15  18  21  24  27  30
4   4   8   12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40
5   5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
6   6   12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60
7   7   14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70
8   8   16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80
9   9   18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90
10  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100
```

But now i want to create it with multidimensional array. Is it possible ? if it possible please show me how. Thanks in advance.

as Example i have something like this

```
$angka = array(
        array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
        array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
    );
```

The result what i want is like the table above

Comment: What does the multidimentional array look like, what is your desired output and what did you try yourself so far?

Comment: @BjörnTantau i have update my question.

Comment: @YVS1102 It's still not clear what your desired result is.

Comment: @BjörnTantau well, i want the same result from i did before

Comment: You can use `foreach` to loop over the arrays.

Comment: Are you expecting something like this? https://eval.in/845363

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$multi = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= 11; $i++) {
    $k = 1;
    $row = [];
    if ($i === 1) {
        $row[] = "x";
    } else {
        $k = $i - 1;
        $row[] = $k;
    }
    for ($j = 2; $j <= 10; $j++) {
        $row[] = $k * $j;
    }
    $multi[] = $row;
}

var_dump($multi);
```